RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback?
I am building a Telegram bot. This code is working:
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda newMessage: True)
def main(newMessage):
    print(newMessage)

bot.polling()

But I need it inside the main() function, await another function instead print(newMessage). Then I should have changed def to async def.
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda newMessage: True)
async def main(newMessage):
    print(newMessage)

bot.polling()

I replaced that and I received this error: RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
and the code not working....
How can I replace def with async def without ERROR and get to the code that works?
(Please explain to a beginner)

Change bot.polling to bot.polling(), also please mention the version of packages you are using in this case telebot.

@PriyanshuJha Thanks for fixing the polling() problem. I use telebot 4.17.0.  telebot in pypi
